# What would a Tesla do if its being tailgated while Autopilot is activated?

Tags: tesla, self-driving

If a Tesla was being driven by Autopilot, and the following vehicle was too close for the speed they're travelling, what (if anything) would the Tesla do?

A human driver might choose to change lanes, speed up, slow down gently, or something more imperative like a brake-check.

If the following vehicle was a bicycle, motorbike, horse or runner, would that be detected as different and result in a different action?

Comment: That would be one fast runner !  Are you thinking if someone is chasing the vehicle ?

Comment: @Pete I suspect that autopilot will page the driver and give up control, but can't find anything as evidence for any action.   Autopilot is not legal in my country, though you can buy the upgraded cameras etc required you can't turn it on.

Comment: I've checked with AI.SE and they do not think its on-topic for Artificial Intelligence.

Comment: @Criggie - Sounds like they need to have a better understanding of what AI encompasses, lol :P

Comment: Well its definitely a product-based question, whereas AI.SE is about theory etc.